# Как исправить ошибку связанную с импортом библиотеки OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

Я когда запустил код у меня появилась ошибка:

```
C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/iliya/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/OpenCV.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\OpenCV.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 175, in bootstrap
    if __load_extra_py_code_for_module("cv2", submodule, DEBUG):
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 28, in __load_extra_py_code_for_module
    py_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\iliya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\iliya\PycharmProjects\OpenCV\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\gapi\__init__.py", line 290, in <module>
    cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я не понимаю почему эта ошибка появилась при импорте библиотеки. Помогите исправить

Вот код:

```
    import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

haystack_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41.png')
needle_img = cv.imread('Images/TMNT 03.04.2022 23_30_41 (1).jpg')

haystack_len = len(haystack_img.shape)
print(haystack_len)
if haystack_len == 3:
    print(haystack_img.shape[-1])

needle_len = len(needle_img.shape)
print(needle_len)
if needle_len == 3:
    print(needle_img.shape[-1])

haystack_img.astype(np.float32)
needle_img.astype(np.float32)





result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

cv.imshow('Result', result)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: Советуют сменить версию Opencv

Comment: @AlexAlex  а на какую?

Comment: 4.5.5.62 или 4.6.0.66

Comment: @AlexAlex  мне говорит что такой версии как 4.5.5.62 нету

Comment: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 4.5.5.62 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 4.5.5.62
`